# Create raster surface from points with barrier

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, interpolation, rasterization

I have a point layer, that represents an elevation in that given point. This I need to create a raster/surface/DEM from, preferably by interpolating by Nearest Neighbour method or some way Liniar between the points. However I only need it inside my barrier which I have as a polygon and polyline layer. I'm trying to use Nearest/Natural Neighbour method with the polygon/polyline layer as processing extent, but this doesn't give the "cut" raster result I'm looking for.

I've tried converting my buffer into a raster and add that under Processing Extent Snap Raster, without getting the desired results.

I have ArcGIS Advanced 10.5.1 with Spatial and 3d Analyst.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been simulating your problem here and unfortunately I have no advanced license, but a normal one. Anyways, I got to the following workflow, which I believe will give you what you want.

1. Create and empty raster covering your study area with the tool **Create Raster Dataset**. Choose your cell size wisely (I would go for the minimum distance between the points)
2. Use the Point to Raster tool to extract the point values and stick them to the raster
3. Create your DEM based on the algorithm you want
4. Clip the raster that is in the barrier polygon

Let me know if that works!

Comment: You don't need first two steps.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am curious about doing this efficiently.

Comment: Interpolate points. Use clip management to clip raster by polygon. Or extract by mask.